Newton-Raphson Method's Convergence
I have a function with three real roots, for which I have to prove the following:
There are three intervals in which, for every initial guess, N-R converges to the root.
I have this Theorem from a Numerical Analisis book:
Let $f$ be a two-times derivable function, $f''(x)>0$, $f(a)f(b)<0$.
Then, $\forall x_0 \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f'(x_0)\neq 0$, N-R method converges when starting in $x_0$.
My question is: can I use this result for an interval? That is: instead of $f''(x)>0, \forall x \in \mathbf{R}$ can I use this: $f''(x)>0, \forall x \in I \subset \mathbf{R}$
Edit: From page 76 of this textbook https://mate.dm.uba.ar/~slassall/Duran_Lassalle_Rossi.pdf

The conditions you mention do not guarantee the convergence of the N-R method... You can easily find counter-examples. Can you specify the source?

Pierre, it is in Spanish, but you can check it here, page 78: https://www.dm.uba.ar/materias/elementos_calculo_numerico_M/2005/1/apunte.pdf

Page 78 deals with general fixed point iterations, not Newton's method. Please provide the correct page number.

The convergence theorem on those course notes does not say what you claim... It says that under certain conditions, if the initial approximation is close enough to the root, the method converges. The result does not provide any information on the  magnitude of the interval.

The standard result on convergence of Newton's method is given by the Kantorovich Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantorovich_theorem

I'm very sorry, the textbook I uploaded has been recently updated and I didn't notice. The link I was talking about is this: https://mate.dm.uba.ar/~slassall/Duran_Lassalle_Rossi.pdf

The start point condition is not strong enough. You need $f(x_0)>0$, which automatically implies $f'(x-0)\ne 0$, to get that the tangent roots stay inside the interval and get closer to the root.

Have a look at  http://www.numdam.org/article/NAM_1869_2_8__17_0.pdf This is the key
